# Add a purchase condition to WooCommerce products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, user-data

I ma trying to add a purchase condition to my WooCommerce products with the following:

```
{$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if ( current_user_can('administrator') || wc_customer_bought_product($current_user->email, $current_user->ID,
// return true
return true;}
```

But I don't know if this code is correct and an advise will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product Id argument is missing from wc_customer_bought_product() function, and you can get more easily the `WP_User` object. Here is a usage example:

```
global $current_user;

if ( is_user_logged_in() && wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->email, $current_user->ID, get_the_id() ) ) {
    // Do something
    echo '<p>' . __("You have already purchased this product before") . '</p>';
}
```